# Куда деть файлы при переводе приложения kivy в apk python?

Tags: python, файлы, kivy, app

В общем. Я делал приложение которое может говорить цифры, для этого я использую файлы с произношением. Но при переводе приложения в apk куда мне деть эти файлы, что бы можно было использовать на телефоне?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо в **buildozer.spec** прописать расширения файлов включаемые в APK и папки, пример:

```
#(list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts. = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,wav
#(list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = audio/guard/*.wav,audio/chisau/*.wav
```

Comment: можно про папки подробнее?

Comment: Ну директории которые ты встраиваешь внутрь apk